# Can one creature be teleported on top of another with Dimensional Scramble?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

The Psion power, [dimensional scramble](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13302), offers a curious group teleport:

> Hit: 1d6 + Intelligence modifier damage, and you teleport the target to a square adjacent to the burst.

While teleportation requires that the destination square be empty (as moves cannot be into occupied squares), there are no prohibitions against teleporting someone *above* someone else.

Are there any rules in place to handle people falling on other people?
Is dimensional scramble a 3x3x1 zone, a 3x3x2 zone, or a 3x3x3 zone by the rules?
Is it possible to iteratively drop people in the same air-based square, so that they all fall in a heap? If not, are there any rules besides common sense that prohibit it?

Comment: Also consider that even if there's only one creature affected, one could conceivably target the square directly above that creature.  The end result of such use could teleport the creature 4 squares high, for 2d10 of falling damage on top of the attack.

Comment: Depending on the size of the burst, yes.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that teleportation which would result in a fall, is negatable via successful save.  So, using the Dimensional Scramble in this manner runs you the chance of not only *not* having creatures fall on top of one another, but also having the creatures *not teleport at all*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Regarding resolving the attacks sequentially to pile up the targets:  I believe it falls into a gray area where it depends on whether or not the target falls as part of resolving the attack.

   To [quote an answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3691/can-forced-movement-be-used-to-dismount-a-rider/3693#3693) from @PatLudwig:

   > The attack sequence if multiple
   >   targets are involved is on pg214 of
   >   the Rules Compendium. Simplified it
   >   is:
   >
   > 1. chose targets
   > 2. roll and resolve an attack on one target
   > 3. repeat step 2 on a different target until finished.

   Based on that, you can resolve them sequentially; teleporting one and then the next. If the target falls as part of resolving the attack, the space is then empty for you to teleport the next into it. **Personally, I would rule no**, they do not fall as part of the attack and therefore the space is not vacant when you move on to resolve the next attack. The falling is a consequence of where they were teleported that occurs after the attack. (But I could see arguments going both ways.)
2. Additionally, if you are teleporting opponents into the air, remember they get a save to negate the teleportation (from PHB3 pg 218):

   > Destination Space: ... If arriving  in 
   >   the destination space would cause the target to fall 
   >   or if that space  is  hindering terrain,  the target can 
   >   make a saving throw. On a save, the  teleportation  is 
   >   negated.
3. Falling on top of someone else: We've always played that the interloper(the one who is falling) scatters using a random d8 roll and falls prone with no negative effect on the person being fallen upon. At the moment, though, I can't back that up with a rules citation.
4. Finally, I agree with @Jeremiah that bursts are a volume using the radius in three dimensions (i.e. a `burst 1` is 3x3x3 cube.

Comment: Nice and thorough.  I agree with the ruling that teleportations are resolved simultaneously, but not for the same reason.  I believe that, while resolved separately, "burst" and "blast" attacks hit all targets at the same moment regardless of the order in which they are rolled.

Answer (score 1):

3x3x3

For bursts vertical distances are measured the same as horizontal distances and they take on a cube shape. Its easy to think in 2D terms with 4e (thanks to the Battlemap) but there is [documentation](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19686342/Rules_Q38A_FAQ__ask_a_simple_question&post_num=5) on bursts being 3D.