# What happens when a creature falls on another creature?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage, falling

If I successfully teleport a creature 4 square above another creature, and it falls, what happens?  Is damage done to one or both?

Comment: similiar question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3825/can-one-creature-be-teleported-on-top-of-another-with-dimensional-scramble

Comment: Accidental Death From Above! (No, wait, that's Battletech.)

Answer (score 5):

*Note: Remember that 4e has a set of rather simplified, abstract rules to cover only situations that come up often. For such rare occurences the GM needs to improvise and make up something new based on the ruleset. With that in mind you can read below.*

As Colin said the creature falling would certainly take the regular amount of damage. As for the other one, creatures generally don't occupy 100% of their grid space. That is quite apparent since realistically you can fit a few average people in a 5x5 feet square. So, it wouldn't be a certain hit on the creature under the falling one.

I think you should roll something versus the **Reflex** of the creature-standing-below or have it make a **Dexterity check** to dodge the falling object/creature. Relevant size between that creature and the one falling should affect the DC/roll as well, since dodging a halfling should be easier than dodging an Adult Dragon that somehow ended falling from a few feet above your head.

For instance:

> Dexterity DC for target to dodge creature/object falling on it = 15
>   +5 DC for every size category over the creature below
>   -5 DC for every size category under the creature below

Something similar can be done if you want to roll vs. Reflex instead of having the target roll a Dexterity check.

Regarding damage in case of a direct hit, there are two variables to consider, **mass** of the falling object and **falling distance** (momentum gained from greater height would make the impact more intense, just like it works for the falling damage).
For damage due to mass you can either set an amount of damage per weight unit (lb) or creature size category, the latter aiming towards simplicity (eg 1d10 per size category over Tiny, or 1d10 per 100 lbs).
For the falling distance, you should should set an amount per square fallen, or even use the formula for falling damage.

In a more realistic sense, I think I would like to use some sort of multiplication between these two factors however that would be easier to keep balanced and would take a few skills in maths and differential analysis to make sure you don't go "unreasonably off the chart".

All in all, you need to make up something. Good luck with that.

Comment: I think using the falling damage (maybe even dividing it between the two creatures) is probably wise, as anything else could potentially become quite unbalanced rather quickly. I like your ideas for setting the dex check DCs.

Answer (score 1):

The creature falling would take damage. I believe falling creatures land prone, so that would mean both creatures could occupy the same space if I am remembering correctly.

I have not found any rules that talk about what happen to the creature already in that square.

Comment: a falling creature trained in acrobatics gets to make an acrobatics check and reduce the damage by half the amount of the check. If they complete avoid damage they are able to land on their feet. In this case I'd give them a free shift into an adjacent square just like standing up from prone when your space is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a written rule, I would keep it simple.

Including factors like size, distance, awareness, etc, figure out whether you consider dodging the falling creature to be easy, medium, or hard (for any person, not based on the person's abilities).

Allow the creature being fallen upon to make an Acrobatics check with a DC determined by Wizard's DC table:

[image: difficulty class by level]

Success: They dodge the falling creature. 
Failure: They take half the falling damage that the falling creature takes.

I would have the person take half of the falling damage because of (a) [Newton's third law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_third_law) and (b) presumably, they at least *tried* to get out of the way and the fall wasn't lined up perfectly to apply *all* of its force directly on them.

Comment: Calm down people; you can put away your pitchforks. I know I mentioned real world physics in 4e. Please forgive me!

Comment: Ok u caught urself on the real world physics, but, would u rule a flatfooted or stunned (or otherwise incapacitated) they take = dmg since they couldnt get out of the way? Or simply rule that you couldnt possible have lined them up perfectly anyway?

Comment: Since its a houserule I'd certainly have no problem changing things up for exceptional circumstances. A stunned or unconcious creature would fail the acrobatics check automatically, but I'd leave it at half damage unless the fall was aimed intentionally. But on the other extreme, no you can't drop a sack full of pixies from a mile above Orcus to slay him from the falling damage outright. This is just a simple baseline to work from.

Comment: Having the person take half damage makes no sense. If a whale falls into a person from 10 feet high, does it make sense for it to take 16 tons worth of damage? Falling damage is already covered by, well, falling damage.